# Router vs VLAN in networking?

Tags: switch, router, vlan, layer2, layer3

Why do we need Routers at all when we have VLAN ?

Vlan breaks the broadcast domain.
Vlan along with the use of SVI can be used for routing.

So why do we need routers for in networking ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your idea.

You cannot get traffic from one VLAN to another VLAN without routing. Either you have a dedicated router, or a layer-3 switch, which is really a router, too. A layer-2 switch with separate VLANs and SVIs still cannot let hosts on one VLAN communicate with hosts on a different VLAN. Frames can be switched at layer-2 on the same VLAN, but you need to strip the frames to get to the packets to route them between VLANs.

Switches are mostly limited to ethernet. Routers are used to connect different physical and data-link protocols, too. Some translating bridges can do some of that at layer-2. For example, WAPs translate layer-2 frames between ethernet and Wi-Fi, but only if they are on the same layer-2 LAN.

Even layer-3 switches usually have fewer resources (RAM, CPU, etc.) than dedicated routers do, and dedicated routers often have special hardware that you do not normally find in switches.

Comment: You write "Even layer-3 switches usually have fewer resources ...than dedicated routers do, "  And you wrote "a layer-3 switch, which is really a router" <-- so what are you talking about

Answer (score 1):

Hence Vlan is layer2 construct . By default same  Vlans on can communicate to each other . In this scenario no routing is required and no router or layer3 devices is required .

But in scenario where different Vlans wants to communicate .Router is required to route traffic between different Vlans . General by default different Vlan traffic won't communicate to each other . To make them accessable router or any layer3 device is mandate to route tràffic among VLANs

Comment: You write "By default same Vlans on can communicate to each other . In this scenario no routing is required" and you write "t in scenario where different Vlans wants to communicate .Router is required" <-- how do those statements not contradict each other?